# Avoiding Git and WordPress conflicts on localhost and webhost?

Tags: wordpress, git, gitlab

So, basically webhost and localhost have conflicts. I haven't merged them yet. I've just done a...

```
git status
git diff HEAD
```

These are the results, some untracked RankMath files on webhost and an upcoming conflict in WordFence plugin logs on WordPress...

```
webhost (PULL): git status
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   wp-content/wflogs/config-transient.php
    modified:   wp-content/wflogs/rules.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    wp-content/uploads/rank-math/rank_math_23e48e66683b46f3bb15aca54a7da030.xml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")


webhost (PULL): git diff HEAD
diff --git a/wp-content/wflogs/config-transient.php b/wp-content/wflogs/config-transient.php
index b34dac3f..5e284575 100644
--- a/wp-content/wflogs/config-transient.php
+++ b/wp-content/wflogs/config-transient.php
@@ -3,4 +3,4 @@
 This file is used by the Wordfence Web Application Firewall. Read 
 more at https://docs.wordfence.com/en/Web_Application_Firewall_FAQ
```

What's the best way to handle this situation? Should i put /wp-content/wflogs/* in .gitignore?

Comment: So, here's what i did. Seemed to work. I'll make this the answer when i get some feedback from the SO-pros out there. I added ```/wp-content/wflogs/``` to ```.gitignore```. Then on localhost I did a ```git update-index --assume-unchanged wp-content/wflogs/config-transient.php```. This seemed to avoid rebase conflicts on webhost.

Comment: You shouldn't need to assume unchanged. Just add it to .gitignore. That would keep localhost from committing it as well. As a general rule, log files should always be ignored. They are specific to the environment that they are created in.

Answer (score 0):

> You shouldn't need to assume unchanged. Just add it to .gitignore. That would keep localhost from committing it as well. As a general rule, log files should always be ignored. They are specific to the environment that they are created in.

– Nilpo

Added to .gitignore this solved the issue